# How can I make a slider in processing.js?

Tags: javascript, processing

I have a program:

```
 noStroke();
fill(0, 255, 162);
var ft = 10;
//Change the diameter
var CSize = 100;
var R = CSize / 2;
var D = CSize;
var C = D * PI / ft;
var A = PI * R * R / ft;
var SimonArea = C * A / D * 2 / ft;
ellipse(200 - CSize / 2,200 - CSize / 2,CSize,CSize);
fill(13, 0, 255);
textSize(20);
text("Circumference = "+C,0,392);
text("Area of Circle = "+A,6,365);
text("1 foot = 10 pixels",19,33);
text("Random numbers associated with the circle =",3,314);
text(SimonArea,3,344);
```

But I can't figure out how to make a slider which can be used to change the variable CSize. I need it so I can change the variable CSize in the program. It is supposed to find the circumference and area of a circle. I don't really care how much time it takes to load the program. The range of the slider should be 0 to 200.

Comment: your program kind of lacks functions. Without the basics of an event driven Processing program, you're not going to get a working slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some good GUI libraries that do it for you. I'm currently using the class Widget that you can find here: http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/115256

To draw a simple slider you can copy this class to yours and draw with a few lines like this:

```
Slider slider;
var CSize = 20f;

void setup(){
  size(200,200);
  slider = new Slider("name", CSize, 0f, 200f, 10, 50, 150, 20, HORIZONTAL);
}
void draw(){
  background(80);
  slider.display();
}

void mouseDragged(){
  slider.mouseDragged();
  CSize = slider.val;
  println("valor: " + CSize);
}

void mouseReleased(){
  slider.mouseReleased();
  CSize = slider.val;
  println("valor: " + CSize);
}
```

P.S.: If you want to use the class Widget, make sure you have copied the four lines with constants above it.